# How to stop memory leaks when using `as_ptr()`?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, rust, ctypes, ffi

Since it's my first time learning systems programming, I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the rules. Now, I got confused about memory leaks. Let's consider an example. Say, Rust is throwing a pointer (to a string) which Python is gonna catch.

In Rust, (I'm just sending the pointer of the `CString`)

```
use std::ffi::CString;

pub extern fn do_something() -> *const c_char {
    CString::new(some_string).unwrap().as_ptr()
}
```

In Python, (I'm dereferencing the pointer)

```
def call_rust():
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(rustLib)
    lib.do_something.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
    c_pointer = lib.do_something()
    some_string = ctypes.c_char_p(c_pointer).value
```

Now, my question is about freeing the memory. I thought it should be freed in Python, but then ownership pops in. Because, [`as_ptr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html#method.as_ptr) seems to take an immutable reference. So, I got confused about whether I should free the memory in Rust or Python *(or both?)*. If it's gonna be Rust, then how should I go about freeing it when the control flow has landed back into Python?

Comment: Note that in this case, there is **no** memory leak. Instead, it is a use-after-free error, which is usually much more destructive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Rust function `do_something` constructs a temporary `CString`, takes a pointer into it, and then *drops the `CString`*. The `*const c_char` is invalid from the instant you return it. If you're on nightly, you probably want `CString#into_ptr` instead of `CString#as_ptr`, as the former consumes the `CString` without deallocating the memory. On stable, you can `mem::forget` the `CString`. Then you can worry about who is supposed to free it.

Freeing from Python will be tricky or impossible, since Rust may use a different allocator. The best approach would be to expose a Rust function that takes a `c_char` pointer, constructs a `CString` for that pointer (rather than copying the data into a new allocation), and drops it. Unfortunately the middle part (creating the `CString`) seems impossible on stable for now: `CString::from_ptr` is unstable.

A workaround would to pass (a pointer to) the *entire `CString`* to Python and provide an accessor function to get the char pointer from it. You simply need to box the `CString` and transmute the box to a raw pointer. Then you can have another function that transmutes the pointer back to a box and lets it drop.

Comment: `CString` is represented as `Box<[u8]>`; `std::raw::Slice` (unstable) shows the representation of that type. Transmuting back and forth is likely to be the best way if you want to transfer ownership.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan `CString` became a `Box<[u8]>` at the same time I added `into_ptr`; before that, it was a `Vec<u8>` .

Comment: @ChrisMorgan This is undocumented though, and unlike `struct Box<T>(*mut T)` it is not obvious that this will never change. Therefore I'm weary to recommend it, especially since a stable `into_ptr`/`from_ptr` is probably only two releases away.

Comment: @Shepmaster: I see that commenting on it based on the *current* source code rather than the *stable* source code is a bad idea. Or rather, transmuting is hazardous. Ah well, at least `mem::transmute::<CString, *const [u8]>()` would fail to compile because of size mismatch.

Comment: Regarding the `into_ptr`, I was using that for a while. But, I thought of switching to stable. Moreover, if you can see the docs (well, I have it locally), the `into_ptr` warns us - *"The pointer must be returned to Rust and reconstituted using `from_ptr` to be properly deallocated. Specifically, one should not use the standard C free function to deallocate this string."* (This really confused me).

Comment: @Waffle'sCrazyPeanut I'd love to hear how I could make that documentation clearer. The important point is that **Rust** must be the thing that frees anything that Rust created.

Comment: @Shepmaster: I understand it now. I got confused because I never thought that it'd be so complicated to just destroy something (like I said, it's my first into systems programming). And, don't worry, the docs are very much clear enough :)

Comment: @delnan Since freeing seems complicated for me in Python (at least for now), I'll go for Rust. You suggested that it's better if I go about defining another function that simply takes the pointer using `from_str` and drop it. It's nice, but before doing that, can you tell me whether this leak is dangerous (if I use the function often)?

Comment: @Waffle'sCrazyPeanut it depends on how long your program will run and how often the function is going to be called. Each time you call the function, memory will be leaked (the amount depends on the length of your string). If you do it very often (and during enough time), you could run out of memory (which would result in a crash). This is not something you would like to have in a web server, for example.

Comment: @aochagavia: I get it. Then, it should better be fixed. Thanks :)